# Get list of videos listed under Events Tab from YouTube

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

How to get videos which are listed under "Events" tab of YouTube?

Trying to fetch using following:

[Youtube Search - Try It !](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#try-it)

Comment: Although it is OK to self-answer, you should separate your question and answer, leaving the question here, and adding your answer as an answer.

Comment: Did you get it to work? Please post your code, and the error it gives when implemented...

Comment: I still didnt get the answer. I just informed that I'm trying to fetch using the link mentioned

Comment: Are you trying to get your own live events, or just popular live events?

Answer (score 1):

To search for live events you're going to want to set `live` as the value for the `eventType` key and `video` as the value for the `type` key.

Your request will look something like this:

```
HTTP GET: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?eventType=live&part=id%2C+snippet&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Objective-C:

```
// Set up your URL
NSString *youtubeApi = @"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?eventType=live&part=id%2C+snippet&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}";
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:youtubeApi];

// Create your request
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

// Send the request asynchronously
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

    // Callback, parse the data and check for errors
    if (data && !connectionError) {
        NSError *jsonError;
        NSDictionary *jsonResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];

        if (!jsonError) {
            NSLog(@"Response: %@", jsonResult);
        }
    }
}];
```

Swift:

```
// Set up your URL
let youtubeApi: String = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?eventType=live&part=id%2C+snippet&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}"
var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: youtubeApi)!

// Create your request
var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

// Send the request asynchronously
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

    // Callback, parse the data and check for errors
    if data != nil && error == nil {
        var err: NSError?
        if let jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary {
            println("Response: \(jsonResult)")
        }
    } else {
        println("Error: \(error)")
    }
})
```

Response:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/zpkE9CJT5UE3J3ftgSZ5oGJd9mI\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 3011,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/eGgYtvB5TXQD0T0QJiElo89I6Sw\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "B9zFbRYW_sk"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-05-17T02:25:30.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC5BMQOsAB8hKUyHu9KI6yig",
    "title": "[On-Air] KBS World Latino",
    "description": "KBS World Latino ha sido lanzado oficialmente el 1 de noviembre! ¡En este canal, se transmitirán los doramas, shows de música y entreteniemnto más ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/B9zFbRYW_sk/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/B9zFbRYW_sk/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/B9zFbRYW_sk/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "kbsworld",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "live"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/lRgnr-IYRKQ7dpUwvBDfpX0Qz3Q\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "8HxN3ZHMbjc"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-01-02T05:10:04.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC5BMQOsAB8hKUyHu9KI6yig",
    "title": "[On-Air] KBS World 24",
    "description": "700만 해외동포와 함께 하는 KBS World 24!!! 이제 해외에서도 KBS의 실시간 뉴스를 고화질의 KBS World 24채널로 시청하실 수 있습니다. KBS World 24 채널은...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8HxN3ZHMbjc/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8HxN3ZHMbjc/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8HxN3ZHMbjc/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "kbsworld",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "live"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/exCIHag5T6lQhpLHOOPZ9Z63lKs\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "wyMOYHiatos"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-05-28T13:50:09.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCLA_DiR1FfKNvjuUpBHmylQ",
    "title": "NASA HDTV",
    "description": "NASA TV airs a variety of regularly scheduled, pre-recorded educational and public relations programming 24 hours a day on its various channels. Programs ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wyMOYHiatos/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wyMOYHiatos/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wyMOYHiatos/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "NASAtelevision",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "live"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/C_dxvfEwfJ1mGWVzbJAVSNHvdpk\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "kRonNPz4MJw"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-04-30T21:07:32.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCzv6uVYjfvE8X-_F3cicWog",
    "title": "إذاعة القرآن الكريم من القاهرة - بث مباشر - Quran Karim",
    "description": "إذاعة القرآن الكريم من القاهرة - بث مباشر - Quran Karim *** هذه الصفحه غير رسميه *** يمكنكم التواصل مع اذاعه القران...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kRonNPz4MJw/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kRonNPz4MJw/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kRonNPz4MJw/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "live"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/DJJYpR9kef3SlbZnsbVcmqDp6Qs\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "9SdaRmrVBZ4"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-04-07T00:15:03.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC8NnosPOvXnm0O1u5YnLQiw",
    "title": "Long-Eared Owl powered by EXPLORE.org",
    "description": "Love Birds Subscribe http://goo.gl/zqy2fE - Watch the Best Moments https://goo.gl/FqdepR Multicam Experience http://goo.gl/PA33mO Facebook ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9SdaRmrVBZ4/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9SdaRmrVBZ4/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9SdaRmrVBZ4/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "live"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```